# C# Attribute to modify methods

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes, cross-cutting-concerns

all. Maybe i've not googled enough, but i can't find any example on this question.

It is possible in C# to create an custom attribute which, applied to a class, modifies all of its methods? For example, adds `Console.WriteLine("Hello, i'm modified method");` as a first line (or it's IL equivalent if it's done at runtime)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but no, its not built in to C#.  As Eric says, this technique is known as Aspect Oriented Programming.

I've used [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) at work, and it is very effective.  It works at compile time, and uses IL-weaving, as opposed to other AOP techniques.

For example, the following attribute will do what you want:

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method | MulticastTargets.Class,
                         AllowMultiple = true,
                         TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public | 
                                                  MulticastAttributes.NonAbstract | 
                                                  MulticastAttributes.Managed)]
class MyAspect : OnMethodInvocationAspect
{
    public override void OnInvocation(MethodInvocationEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, i'm modified method");

        base.OnInvocation(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

You simply apply `MyAspect` as an attribute on your class, and it will be applied to every method within it.  You can control how the aspect is applied by modifying the `TargetmemberAttributes` property of the `MulticastAttributeUsage` property.  In this example, I want to restrict it to apply only to public, non-abstract methods.

There's a lot more you can do so have a look (at AOP in general).

Comment: Thx for example, that's what i needed. 
How i understand, such technique gives no perfomance loss at runtime?

Comment: The best way to satisfy your performance concerns is to measure the performance and see if it is good enough.  However, a simple thing to do is to just open up the resulting assembly in reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and look at the resulting code.  See what you think.  We haven't seen any problematic performance issues from using this technique at work.

Answer (score 6):

No. What you are looking for is aspect oriented programming ([AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)).

With AOP you specify a pointcut, a place where you want to weave in code, and the code you want to executed at that point. Tracing is the standard example for AOP. You specify a set of methods and the the weaver/compiler to add you log/tracing call at the beginning or the end of that methods.

Comment: There are more .NET-AOP Extensions at the end of the linked wikipedia page (footnote 6)