# role based access to methods

Tags: c#, .net, security, methods, security-roles

I'm implementing system which uses role based access to different methods in classes. For example to perform any action I need to check whether user which uses it can do it.

I can write in each method:

```
if(User.IsInRole ...) {
} else {
return ... throw ... whatever
}
```

I was thinking about automating this process for example by adding attributes to this methods or maybe any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at 'Aspect Oriented Programming' (AOP) libraries -- and the answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656621/c-attribute-to-modify-methods).
You can use AOP to add the role check code automatically.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you use principals things are already there...

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "A role available on your principal")]
public void Foo()
{
  // Will throw an exception if the principal does not have the required role
  // Otherwise the method will execute normally
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the check once at construction time, and throw (or return NULL from the factory) if the security condition is not met.  Thereafter, holding a reference to a given model object is enough proof that you passed the security check at some earlier point.  If you are worried that this could cause [TOCTTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check-to-time-of-use) issues, ensure that these objects become unusable at the end of an application-defined concept of "game turn" (typically the database transaction); this is a good practice anyway.

This approach of security is called [capability discipline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security). Think of your objects as boxes that have [some authority inside them](http://www.erights.org/elib/capability/ode/ode-capabilities.html#patt-coop) (in their private variables). By pressing the buttons on the box, you can only exercise a tailored down fraction of this authority in the ways that the programmer of the object allows you to.

For example, say you are writing a calendar application with an SQL backend. There is the `SQLTransaction` object, which doesn't outlive the transaction (as per above) but still it has all the rights to all the tables that the application uses. That's a lot of power that you don't want to be passing around to users of your API (explicitly or by mistake, think SQL injection). Instead you hand out `User` objects that model the authority to write only to that user's row in the Users table; also a `User` can create, read, update, delete `Appointment` objects, which similarly represent limited authority in the Appointments table.

To maintain RBAC throughout your API, you must ensure that the following hold:

1. Only legitimate users can get access to the `User` object that represents them. This is where you wire up the authentication system into the `User` constructor;
2. The `User` objects do not [leak authority](http://wiki.erights.org/wiki/Walnut/Secure_Distributed_Computing/Capabilities#Carefully_design_the_API_so_that_capabilities_do_not_leak), ie you have to audit your API to make sure that by exercising method calls on a `User` (or any related object they return, recursively) you cannot read or alter any resources that do not belong to this user. This is where you can apply the [facet](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?FacetPattern) pattern — eg `User.GetAppointments()` returns real `Appointment` instances for appointments created by this user, but read-only wrappers for those created by someone else.